# Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 ethernet card randomly disconnecting

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking, openvz, realtek

System information:

- kernel: latest OPENVZ kernel (2.6.32-042stab140.4)
- centos version: CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
- network card type: 
  Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)

Problem:
**We have a strange problem with our server. Network is disconnected every now and then, randomly. Sometimes it is up for some days and then network disconnects, sometimes it disconnects dayly, it happened it was up for 2 weeks also, so it is totally unreliable. There are no errors in messages.log or dmesg.log or any other logs. Only thing we see is that the server is disconnected from network. Using a KVM i could log in and restart the network card with commands "ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0". After that the network is back online.**

What we tried:

- Installing and updating kernel
- Current kernel uses r8169 driver, and we know that some people solved their network issues by installing r8168 driver. We did that, the problem still exists.

Network config:

## /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=D4:3D:7E:****
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=144.76.****
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
SCOPE="peer 144.76.****"
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2a01:4f8:200:****
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=eth0
```

## /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0:

```
ADDRESS0=0.0.0.0
NETMASK0=0.0.0.0
GATEWAY0=144.76.219.1
```

/etc/resolv.conf and /etc/sysconfig/network is setup correctly too

commands and their output which you might need to help me:

## ethtool eth0

```
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

## ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:3D:7E:EC:F1:64
          inet addr:144.76.**  Bcast:144.76.**  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: 2a01:4f8:** Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::d63d:** Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:216416 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:236235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:25416051 (24.2 MiB)  TX bytes:112658399 (107.4 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:41671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:7606777 (7.2 MiB)  TX bytes:7606777 (7.2 MiB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet6 addr: fe80::1/128 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:217176 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:194950 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:105725409 (100.8 MiB)  TX bytes:20479815 (19.5 MiB)
```

## ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:3d:7e:ec:f1:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 144.76.** peer 144.76.**/32 brd 144.76.** scope global eth0
    inet6 2a01:4f8:** scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d63d:7eff:** scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/void
    inet6 fe80::1/128 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
vzethdev                8245  0
pio_kaio               14060  0
pio_nfs                19043  0
pio_direct             30148  2
pfmt_raw                3333  0
pfmt_ploop1             6703  2
ploop                 120433  11 pio_kaio,pio_nfs,pio_direct,pfmt_raw,pfmt_ploop1
simfs                   5189  0
vzrst                 206937  0
nf_nat                 23122  1 vzrst
nf_conntrack_ipv4       9650  2 nf_nat
nf_defrag_ipv4          1523  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
vzcpt                 156425  1 vzrst
nfs                   449026  3 pio_nfs,vzrst,vzcpt
lockd                  78281  2 vzrst,nfs
fscache                61345  1 nfs
auth_rpcgss            46116  1 nfs
nfs_acl                 2655  1 nfs
sunrpc                274118  6 pio_nfs,nfs,lockd,auth_rpcgss,nfs_acl
nf_conntrack           81593  4 vzrst,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,vzcpt
vziolimit               3775  0
vzdquota               55467  0 [permanent]
ip6t_REJECT             4447  0
ip6table_mangle         3629  0
ip6table_filter         3025  0
ip6_tables             19020  2 ip6table_mangle,ip6table_filter
xt_length               1330  0
xt_hl                   1539  0
xt_tcpmss               1615  0
xt_TCPMSS               3549  0
iptable_mangle          3453  0
iptable_filter          2897  2
xt_multiport            2772  2
xt_limit                2126  0
xt_dscp                 2065  0
ipt_REJECT              2423  19
ip_tables              18183  2 iptable_mangle,iptable_filter
vzevent                 2171  1
vznetdev               18984  4
vzmon                  25679  5 vzrst,vzcpt,vznetdev
vzdev                   2725  5 vzethdev,vziolimit,vzdquota,vznetdev,vzmon
ipv6                  342460  90 vzrst,vzcpt,ip6t_REJECT,ip6table_mangle
ext3                  240851  1
jbd                    80628  1 ext3
freq_table              4944  0
mperf                   1565  0
intel_pstate           14660  0
ppdev                   8321  0
parport_pc             22658  0
parport                37265  2 ppdev,parport_pc
iTCO_wdt                7342  0
iTCO_vendor_support     3064  1 iTCO_wdt
r8169                  76421  0
mii                     5544  1 r8169
i2c_i801               13273  0
i2c_core               29164  1 i2c_i801
sg                     29542  0
lpc_ich                13579  0
mfd_core                1935  1 lpc_ich
shpchp                 29554  0
ext4                  431830  3
jbd2                   93732  1 ext4
mbcache                 8201  2 ext3,ext4
raid1                  33193  3
sd_mod                 37126  8
crc_t10dif              1217  1 sd_mod
ahci                   43194  6
xhci_hcd              181527  0
video                  21990  0
output                  2417  1 video
wmi                     6287  0
dm_mirror              14904  0
dm_region_hash         12189  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                  9938  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
dm_mod                102855  2 dm_mirror,dm_log
```

## lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
        Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
        Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci-hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
        Memory at f7c16000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at f7c14000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
        Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
        Memory behind bridge: df200000-df3fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000df400000-00000000df5fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d5) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
        Memory at f7c13000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
        Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
        Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
        I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
        I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
        I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
        I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
        I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
        Memory at f7c12000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
        Memory at f7c11000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
        Kernel modules: i2c-i801

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
        I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
        Memory at f0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169

03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=03, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=32
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [80] Express PCI/PCI-X Bridge, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7816
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Kernel modules: shpchp
```

Even when network was down "cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier" echoed "1" and  cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate echoed "up" so network card was connected....

So what is up ? I read on many forums that this card might have issues and buggy. What do you suggest? Am i right that this problem is definitely hardware issue/ or driver bug/issue. I think the solution would be to get a new attached network card and disable this onboard card. What do you think, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

" I think the solution would be to get a new attached network card and disable this onboard card. " is absolutely the correct answer. Realtec cards are (and I'm being polite) not server grade technology - if the driver bugginess is not enough reason, consider the extra burden they put on the CPU compared to decent hardware.

I would always replace these cards with an Intel chipset card (but there are plenty of other reputable chipsets) on anything but a Windows desktop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i contacted the company providing the dedicated server, they refuse to add a network card for free, they think i don't have enough proof that this issue is hardware related :O

Comment: Change providers. Any provider using realtec cards do not take uptime seriously.  I would point out that if the problem is not hardware related its network related or non-standard driver related and ask them how they would solve it.

Comment: Terrible support, like i exchanged several emails, sent them the information above, but they are telling me that this does not prove that the problem is hardware related. They still say problem might by software related. Ridiculous. Anyway now they will change the whole server (instead of adding that extra network card :D ) saying they will make an exception this time...
This server is not rented by me, it is rented by a company who i am helping out, but i will encourage them to change.
I also think this is not the way to treat people. Hopefully the new server will not have any problems.

Comment: And even on a Windows desktop.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using `irqbalance`, helped me once mitigate a similar issue
2. If possible, can you check your switch logs? There's a chance that `Port Speed Negotiation` isn't set to `auto`, and if it is, try manually setting it to `1Gbps`
3. Stupid but, you never know, check/replace the patch cord. It might look & feel fine, but there **CAN** be one bent pin which can do this kind of stuff. **Source:** *past experience*

Comment: Thank you for the ideas and recommendations. I can't access the switch logs, it is a dedicated server.
I will ask the company to change the patch cable.

Isn't irqbalance is balancing performance, and cpu related? What does it have to do with network?

Comment: It is not, `irqbalance` balances interrupt requests, which can be sent to the CPU from any hardware. Sometimes they get sort of lost in the abyss, which can cause issues like you have. As @davidgo pointed out - Realtek is not a server grade card, and I agree, these cards tend to fail more than any other card. I'm not saying `irqbalance` will save the day, however there is no harm in trying since you can't really debug your server on a hardware level

Comment: Thank you finally hosting company agreed to replace the whole server, instead of adding extra card/replacing cables etc.
But your information was very useful, hopefully others who wonder here might use it.
Thank you for your time!

(I upvoted your answer, but i went for replacement as davidgo suggested, that is why i choose he's answer for now.)